# Java change the text of a JLabel after button

Tags: java, jlabel, settext

I'm trying to learn Java and because of that I'm just trying some stuff out. Now I'm trying to change the text of a JLabel after the click of a button. I've tried reading about it on this website but couldn't find where I went wrong. I really hope someone here can help me.

Below you can find my code. What I'm trying is when button 'b1' is clicked, the text of FirstText is changed to 'Clicked!'. But for me, the screen stays the same and the text is not changed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class vlaggenquiz extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
public JLabel FirstTitle, FirstText;
public JButton b1;

public vlaggenquiz() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    //Maakt tekst en buttons aan voor eerste scherm
    JLabel FirstTitle = new JLabel ("TITLE!");
    JLabel FirstText = new JLabel ("Hello there!");
    b1 = new JButton ("Click");
    b1.addActionListener(this);


    //Bepaald tekstgrootte titel
    FirstTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));

    //Bepaald font tekst
    FirstText.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));

    //Centreert de teksten
    FirstTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    FirstText.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    //Voegt beide teksten en button toe
    add(FirstTitle, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(FirstText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(b1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    //Voegt ruimte to aan de zijkanten binnen app
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    FirstText.setText("Clicked!");
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vlaggenquiz");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComponent newContentPane = new vlaggenquiz();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You're shadowing your variables. Don't re-declare them in the constructor or initialization methods.

Comment: Replace `JLabel FirstText = new JLabel ("Hello there!");` with `FirstText = new JLabel ("Hello there!");`  and `JLabel FirstTitle = new JLabel ("TITLE!");` with `FirstTitle = new JLabel ("TITLE!");` , because you declared them twice, and the ones you use have never been initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked.